# Replace price pfister old shower faucet

Tags: plumbing, shower, faucet, cartridge

My old Price Pfister shower faucet is leaking, so I removed the handle to see what kind of stems they use.

I haven't seen this kind of stems anywhere. Does anyone know what part they are?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: you will most likely need to remove the stem and take it to your local hardware store to be matched up.  Or it may just need a new washer, that can be replaced.

Comment: IMHO, that is a _very_ old faucet. I've had PP faucets for 30 years in our house and have never seen one with script labeling on the handle like that. I'd guess it's probably from the 50s or 60s. Also, if you'll take the [tour] and a browse through [what's on-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), you'll notice that asking for pricing/shopping recommendations is _not_ on-topic, so I've removed that part of your question.

Comment: Generally a local hardware store will have a booklet that can be used to match the valve as RMDman says. They make extended sockets that fit over the hex end on the valve - called a "shower valve wrench".

Answer (score 1):

Price Pfister has many valve stems on the market and it would be near impossible to find the exact replacement for your shower with just the pictures  you've provided.  You're probaby looking for something that resembles the valve stem shown below from Lowes.
[image]

You'll need to turn off the water to the shower and remove the stem  by turning that nut counterclockwise. Take the stem to your home store or a plumbing supply store and they will be able to match it. If you just need a washer or "o" ring, they'll be able to fix you up.